# Why MySQL does not accept my foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have 26 tables that are very dependent from each other. I crated each table and then executed in the database through `MySQL Workbench`. Then I build the model where I linked those tables creating the foreign keys. I exported that back in to metadata and I had now the complete code of the tables with the proper foreign data created by the application, so I made not mistakes.

But when I put the file in my server to run by phpMyAdmin, I get a 150 error that does not specify where it is. I Googled it but each case is different and mine is that the FK are not the auto incremented field, but a string field called UT that I created which has the Time Unit when I created a row.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `eduardo8_plataforma`.`aplicativo` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `ut` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  `nome` VARCHAR(99) NOT NULL ,
  `ver` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `descr` VARCHAR(254) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `tag` VARCHAR(254) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `url` VARCHAR(254) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `cad` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `obj` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `tab` VARCHAR(254) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `dbn` VARCHAR(254) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `dbu` VARCHAR(254) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `dbs` VARCHAR(254) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `nome` (`nome` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `ut_UNIQUE` (`ut` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_swedish_ci;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `eduardo8_plataforma`.`modulo` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `ut` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  `app` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `lic` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `tipo` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `nome` VARCHAR(99) NOT NULL ,
  `classe` VARCHAR(99) NOT NULL ,
  `obj` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `ut_UNIQUE` (`ut` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_swedish_ci;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `eduardo8_plataforma`.`modulo_app` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `ut` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  `app` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  `modulo` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_modulo_app_modulo1` (`modulo` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_modulo_app_aplicativo1` (`app` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `ut_UNIQUE` (`ut` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_modulo_app_modulo1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`modulo` )
    REFERENCES `eduardo8_plataforma`.`modulo` (`ut` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_modulo_app_aplicativo1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`app` )
    REFERENCES `eduardo8_plataforma`.`aplicativo` (`ut` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_swedish_ci;
```

The table that worked (after answers):

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `eduardo8_plataforma`.`modulo_app` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `ut` VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_swedish_ci' UNIQUE NOT NULL ,
  `app` VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_swedish_ci' NOT NULL ,
  `modulo` VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_swedish_ci' NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_modulo_app_modulo1` (`modulo` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_modulo_app_aplicativo1` (`app` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `ut_UNIQUE` (`ut` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_modulo_app_modulo1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`modulo` )
    REFERENCES `eduardo8_plataforma`.`modulo` (`ut` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_modulo_app_aplicativo1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`app` )
    REFERENCES `eduardo8_plataforma`.`aplicativo` (`ut` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_swedish_ci;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the `CREATE INDEX` clauses before the foreign keys, as foreign key cannot reference non-indexed field.

Comment: How do I put the FK declaration after the table creation or the index creation inside the table declaration?

Comment: I tried the way you said and updated the code in the question, but I still get the 150 error code.

Answer (score 2):

The short story is that a foreign key should reference a candidate key column. That is, it should reference a column that is declared either

- primary key, or
- not null unique.

A standard SQL dbms will raise an error if you reference a column that isn't unique. MySQL should, too, but it won't.

[Mysql Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) say

> . . . the system does not enforce a requirement that the referenced columns
>   be UNIQUE or be declared NOT NULL. The handling of foreign key
>   references to nonunique keys or keys that contain NULL values is not
>   well defined for operations such as UPDATE or DELETE CASCADE. You are
>   advised to use foreign keys that reference only UNIQUE (including
>   PRIMARY) and NOT NULL keys.

If you need non-unique data from another table, join it in a query, or join it in a view.

Comment: It is the UT the main index for the foreign keys.

Comment: [Mysql Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) say "the system does not enforce a requirement that the referenced columns be UNIQUE or be declared NOT NULL. The handling of foreign key references to nonunique keys or keys that contain NULL values is not well defined for operations such as UPDATE or DELETE CASCADE. You are advised to use foreign keys that reference only UNIQUE (including PRIMARY) and NOT NULL keys."

Comment: I tried the way you said and updated the code in the question, but I still get the 150 error code.

Comment: Edit your question, and include what you tried. Paste actual code.